# Is there a way to tag links so that they are not modified on web.archive.org?

Tags: archive.org

A website I maintain contains links to an external dynamic site that is not well represented in the Wayback Machine.  So when the wayback machine converts those links into https://web.archive.org/web/yyyymmddHHMMSS/https://example.com/dynamic-tool, for example, the links are effectively broken.

Is there a way to tag links so that they continue to point to the original target when they are archived on web.archive.org?

Answer (score 0):

Wayback Machine is not able to archive all types of dynamic pages, so the first that you should check rather than the URL are the characterists of the targets.

Despite of being dynamic or not, not all the websites are archived.

As a webmaster you might get insights from other webmasters in [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

---

From [WAYBACK MACHINE GENERAL INFORMATION](https://help.archive.org/help/wayback-machine-general-information/)

> **How do you archive dynamic pages?**
>
> There are many different kinds of dynamic pages, some of which are easily stored in an archive and some of which fall apart completely. When a dynamic page renders standard html, the archive works beautifully. When a dynamic page contains forms, JavaScript, or other elements that require interaction with the originating host, the archive will not contain the original site’s functionality.

---

> **Do you collect all the sites on the Web?**
>
> No, the Archive collects web pages that are publicly available. We do not archive pages that require a password to access, pages that are only accessible when a person types into and sends a form, or pages on secure servers. Pages may not be archived due to robots exclusions and some sites are excluded by direct site owner request.